# SQL query to LINQ using group / sum / having

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I've been trying to translate following query from SQL to LINQ, main purpose of my query is to find two or more transactions by the same Sender in which the amount's sum is >= 2000

```
SELECT t.TXN_SENDER_ID,
       s.SEN_FIRSTNAME,
       s.SEN_LASTNAME,
       SUM(t.TXN_AMOUNT)
FROM   TRANSACTIONS t
INNER JOIN SENDERS s ON s.SEN_ID = t.TXN_SENDER_ID
WHERE  t.TXN_DATE BETWEEN Dateadd(YEAR, -3, Getdate()) AND Getdate()
GROUP  BY t.SENDER_ID, s.SENDER_NAME, s.SENDER_LASTNAME
HAVING SUM(t.TXN_AMOUNT) > 2000
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
var query = from t in context.TRANSACTIONS
            join s in context.SENDERS on t.TXN_SENDER_ID equals s.SEN_ID
            group new { t, s } by new { t.TXN_SENDER_ID, s.SEN_FIRSTNAME, s.SEN_LASTNAME, t.TXN_AMOUNT } into gr
            where (gr.Sum(x => x.t.TXN_AMOUNT) > 1000)
            select new { gr.Key.TXN_AMOUNT, gr.Key.SEN_FIRSTNAME, gr.Key.SEN_LASTNAME };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is not "working"? What is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you haven't answered my question, but looking at your sql query you want to filter data on `TXN_DATE`.  My best guess:

```
DateTime dtFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3);
DateTime dtTo = DateTime.Today;

var query = from t in context.TRANSACTIONS
            .Where(tr=>tr.TXN_DATE>=dtFrom && tr.TXN_DATE<=dtTo)
            join s in context.SENDERS on t.TXN_SENDER_ID equals s.SEN_ID
            group new { t, s } by new { t.TXN_SENDER_ID, s.SEN_FIRSTNAME, s.SEN_LASTNAME, t.TXN_AMOUNT } into gr
            where (gr.Sum(x => x.t.TXN_AMOUNT) >= 2000)
            select new
            {
                gr.Key.TXN_SENDER_ID, 
                gr.Key.SEN_FIRSTNAME,
                gr.Key.SEN_LASTNAME,
                gr.Sum(a=>a.TXN_AMOUNT)
            };
```

Comment: Well, I was a bit lost on how to do the date filtering properly but this helped a lot. Thank you!